# Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac のドキュメントアウトラインで#regionが入れ子になって表示されてしまう。

Tags: c#, visual-studio

下のように`#region`を書くと、ドキュメントアウトラインで入れ子になって表示されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

A、B、Cを並列（同じレベル）にするにはどうすれば良いですか？

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    #region A
    private void A()
    {

    }
    #endregion 

    #region B
    private void B()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region C
    private void C()
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: 手元のVisual Studio 2019では、そもそもソースコードに対してドキュメントアウトラインは表示されませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac 2019 だと思いますが、こちらに上がっていておそらくまだ未解決です。
さっきインストールした私の環境でもおきました。

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1142413/the-regions-are-not-shown-correctly-on-the-documen.html

あまり投票されていないので、ログインして投票すれば修正される可能性は上がるかもしれません。

余談ですが、古いMacに残っていたVisual Studio for Mac 2017でもさっき試してみましたがそちらでは正しく表示されました。

ちなみにこちらも類似の報告ですが、なぜか閉じられていますね。
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1012864/document-outline-shows-wrong-hierarchy-when-region.html