# Visual Studio Community 2019 for Macでコードをいくつかに区切って「ドキュメントアウトライン」パネルから、 各メソッドにアクセスしたいです。

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
    #region
    // ...
    #endregion
```

は[入れ子になってしまい使えない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72526/visual-studio-community-2019-for-mac-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A6%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7region%E3%81%8C%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86/72548#72548)ので、
他に方法は何かありませんか？

Xcodeだと`//MARK:` などでメソッドをグループ化して表示できるので、
とても便利で、同じようなことがしたいです。

あるいは、
このようにグループ化しなくても、目的のメソッドを素早く表示する方法があれば、
しりたいです。
VSで開発されている方はどのように目的のメソッドを表示しているのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Macでは対応して無さそうですが、こんな記事があります。[How to show code outline in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793892/9014308) 記事のコメントにありますが、Visual Studio Codeに切り替えて探してみては？

Comment: Visual Studio Codeで試してみましたが、C#だと今のところシンボルがうまくリストアップされないようです。

Comment: VSCodeだとちょうどこんなIssue [Outline: support for `//#region` fold regions #51364](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51364) がありますが、まだCloseしていません。類似でこれ [Extended `#region` support (outline, refactor region name) #107084](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107084) がありますが、中の人からは既にサポート済みと思われているようです。